# In Apache Atlas, is there a way to delete all the entities?

Tags: solr, cassandra, apache-atlas

During debug of some integrations with Apache Atlas it gets very messy (eg. a lot of almost the same entities but with just a bit different name). Is there is a way to delete all of them **without deleting the whole graph database**? Because in that case, it takes ages for Atlas to create all the types and internal data tables.

I use Cassandra and Solr. I know how to do it for Solr, but not sure which Cassandra tables I should clean up?

Answer (score 0):

- drop keyspace janograph
- drop keyspace atlas_audit

Comment: It doesn't help - it still spends a lot of time on re-recreating something.

Comment: Do you mean it takes a long time after restart Atlas? In may case it's very fast to delete all data in Atlas...and we have a lot of entities and relations...

Comment: Yes, restart takes 10-30 minutes to re-create schema after deletion. Question is specifically about deleting entities, not the schema